# Send a PUT/GET/POST request to JHipster in one single transaction

Tags: jhipster

I am quite new to Jhipster and have problem understanding some of its functionalities. Hence here is my question.

I have the following two microservices.
Microservice 1 (MS1) has the following data structures in Java:

```
Lead {
Customer customer;
Deal deal;
}

Customer{
Integer phoneNumber;
etc...
}

Deal{
Integer value;
etc...
}
```

Microservice 2 (MS2) is a JHipster generated database.
The DB only has the following SQL tables :

```
CUSTOMER
LEAD
```

When changes happen in Microservice 1, I send 2 separate PUT requests from MS1 to MS2.

- first a request to update CUSTOMER through the `/customer` API in MS2
- if update is OK, then send a request to update DEAL `/deal` API in MS2

For a successful update for Lead, PUT requests to Customer, Deal should all be OK. If updating one table fails, all should fail.

Hence, I would like to avoid sending 2 separate requests to avoid a case where CUSTOMER request is OK and DEAL request fails for whatever reason.
If possible, I would like to send one single transaction throught an API such as `/lead` that udpates the two table..

What is the best way I can achieve this without creating an extra table for LEAD?
e.g., a layer/service that I should generate using Jhipster.
If possible (but not necessary), I would like to avoid touching code that are frequently regenerated. (e.g., Customer, Deal)

Please kindly direct me to a documentation too if one already exist. They are quite hard to understand so I am not sure if any current one specifically addresses this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue when directly exposing JPA entities from a CRUD REST API.
Your persistence model does not need to be your API model.

If 2 entities are related and should be updated within same transaction, it means that they should be updated with one atomic API request.

So, you could define a new resource with a DTO combining your 2 entities, exposed by a new API that you would code manually (so no need for an additional table).

As you are using microservices architecture, you could have similar situation also between MS1 and MS2 and here you could not use a transaction, you could then have to implement remediation.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that I should create a new jhipster entity, that has no fields in itself, but have relationship with Customer and Deal. The end result is that I have a Lead java object, LeadDTO java object etc for the API model. But how can I make sure that the persistence model do not contain this newly created Lead entity? Is there a specific file that I should delete after code generation?

Comment: No I was not thinking to use `jhipster entity` because it would probably create more things than what you need (you don't need persistence) and deleting them might be error-prone, I was just thinking to implement it manually by implementing a Resource, a DTO and a Service. Don't over use code generation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument